# How to use raw socket in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp

i try to send a selfmade tcp-packet via raw socket in python3 (with windows 10). Inside the ip-header i want to set protocol to TCP (=6).

The paket i send is:

```
E\x00\x00\x00\xd41\x00\x00\xff\x06\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\xb29\xc0\xa8\xb2\x01
```

but I receive (and wireshark detects the same)

```
E\x00\x00FN\xe7\x00\x00\x80\xff\x00\x00\n\xac\x02e\n\xac
```

so now it  is 255 (uknown)

```
srcport = 11001

def sendTCP(dest_ip, dest_port,fin, syn, rst, psh, ack, urg):

    payload = b'[TESTING]\n'

    ip = make_ip(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, source_ip, dest_ip)
    tcp = make_tcp(srcport, dest_port, payload, 123, 0, fin, syn, rst, psh, ack, urg)
    packet = ip + tcp + payload

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
    s.sendto(packet, (dest_ip, 0))

    ans = s.recv(1024)
    print(ans)


def make_ip(proto, srcip, dstip, ident=54321):
    saddr = socket.inet_aton(srcip)
    daddr = socket.inet_aton(dstip)
    ihl_ver = (4 << 4) | 5
    return struct.pack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , 
                   ihl_ver, 0, 0, ident, 0, 255, proto, 0, saddr, daddr)

def make_tcp(srcport, dstport, payload, seq=123, ackseq=0,
         fin=False, syn=False, rst=False, psh=False, ack=False, urg=False,
         window=5840):
    offset_res = (5 << 4) | 0
    flags = (fin | (syn << 1) | (rst << 2) | 
         (psh <<3) | (ack << 4) | (urg << 5))
    return struct.pack('!HHLLBBHHH', 
                   srcport, dstport, seq, ackseq, offset_res, 
                   flags, window, 0, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sendTCP('10.172.2.101',80, False, True, False, False, False, False)
```

Comment: The difference you highlighted is not the only change in the data you send and receive. I don't really understand sockets but shouldn't you get the exact same data on both sides?

Comment: If you insert a print(packet) after or before s.sendto.. , and post the result, then it's more easy to find the problem.

Comment: I think your problem might be byte ordering. Look into htonl/htons and ntohl/ntohs functions in socket module.